# How to do 'generic type hinting' of functions (i.e 'function templates') in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, type-hinting, mypy

I'm pretty sure, this has been asked before, but I don't know, what to search for..

I want to type hint a "generic" function (like a function template in C++)

e.g. (this example makes no sense at all - it's just for demonstration)

```
def foo(fn: Callable[Any, Any], args: Any) -> Any:
    return fn(args)
```

I want to use this function in a context where I have full type information, so I hope I can get rid of any `Any`.

```
def bar() -> int:
    func: Callable[[str], int] = lambda arg: len(arg)
    return foo(func, "Hurz")
```

One way of course would be to just explicitly turn `foo` into `(Callable[[str], int], str) -> int`, but I'm looking for the generic approach.

I guess what I'm looking for has something to do with [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics), but I can't see how to use them to create "function templates".

Comment: `(fn: Callable[[A], R], arg: A) -> R`?

Comment: What are `A` and `R`? `foo` might be part of a package and does not know the types it's being used with..

Comment: ...they're the generic types, the `TypeVar`s.

Comment: ok, `TypeVar` was, what I should have been looking for (rather than `Generics`) - thanks. If you want to turn this into an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `typing` has two parts to do what is commonly known as [generic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) or [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), or simply "Generics" or "Templates":

- the [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to define a *generic placeholder* such as `T`, and
- the [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) to define a *generic type* such as `List`.

Both together form fully parametrisable types such as `List[T]`. Since functions are inbuilt, the `def` keyword naturally defines generic types – only `TypeVar` is needed.

Simply define one `TypeVar` for each type placeholder needed in a signature:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable

T = TypeVar('T')
R = TypeVar('R')

def foo(fn: Callable[[T], R], args: T) -> R:
    return fn(args)
```